# adding sum rows in column in pandas without scientific notation and nan

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I was able to generate this df

```
    downloads   url_info_hostname   date            Size
0   9829        url1.com            2018-03-01      1.0
1   1285651465  url2.com            2018-03-01      868789.0
2   1079238     url3.com            2018-03-01      17121.0
3   77305525    url4.com            2018-03-01      23464.0
```

Which works fine. I added this :

```
print ("Daily sum of downloads: %s" % (sum(df1['downloads'])))
print ("Total data (GB) transferred %s" % (sum(df1['Size'])))
```

The problem is when I export csv of course I am missing the print out above.

When I try to add it as apart of the dataframe it converts everything under downloads in to scientific notation. 
I tried to do this:

```
df1.loc['Daily sum of downloads'] = pd.Series(df1[‘downloads'].sum(), index = [‘downloads’])
df1.loc['Total data (GB) transferred'] = pd.Series(df1['Size'].sum(), index = [‘downloads’])
```

Also every thing has NaN.

I'd a data frame that looks like this:

```
downloads   url_info_hostname   date            Size
    0   9829        url1.com            2018-03-01      1.0
    1   1285651465  url2.com            2018-03-01      868789.0
    2   1079238     url3.com            2018-03-01      17121.0
    3   77305525    url4.com            2018-03-01      23464.0
    4
    5   Daily sum of downloads: 1364046057
    6   Total data (GB) transferred 909375.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a row called sum using loc and format the column

```
df.loc['sum', ['downloads', 'Size']] = df.sum()
df['downloads'] = df['downloads'].apply(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x))

    downloads   url_info_hostname   date        Size
0   9829        url1.com            2018-03-01  1.0
1   1285651465  url2.com            2018-03-01  868789.0
2   1079238     url3.com            2018-03-01  17121.0
3   77305525    url4.com            2018-03-01  23464.0
sum 1364046057  NaN                 NaN         909375.0
```

Comment: That works but I was trying to make a new line. for each item following your example what I am missing here? Looks like it should work `df1.loc['Daily sum of downloads: ', ['downloads']] = df1.sum()
df1.loc['Total data (GB) Transferred: ', [‘Size’]] = df1.sum()
df1['downloads'] = df1['downloads'].apply(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x))`